# How to identify groups of three identical numbers in a list

Tags: python, list

I have a simple list where:

```
a = [1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1]
```

I am trying to find a way to determine when three ones appear adjacent to each other. So the output would say that there are two instances of this, based on the list above. The other posts I've read seem to use itertools.groupby(), but I'm not familiar with it so I was wondering if there is another way?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `groupby`? That's the easiest and most natural way to do it.

Comment: Aside: how many adjacent set of `1` in `a = [1,1,1,1]`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way, using `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

a = [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]    
adjacencies = [(item,  len(list(group))) for item,  group in groupby(a)]
ones = sum(item == 1 and length >= 3 for item,  length in adjacencies)
print ones
```

Here is another way, not using `groupby`:

```
a = [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
triplets = zip(a[0:], a[1:], a[2:])
ones = sum(set(t) == {1} for t in triplets)
print ones
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one using `itertools.groupby`

```
import itertools

a = [1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1]

n=0
for x in itertools.groupby(a):
    c = 1
    for y in x[1]:
        c+=1
    if c==3:
        n+=1
```